# If $f$ analytic on $\mathbb{D}$, show that $|f(z)| \leq |z|\left| \frac{z^2-r^2}{1-r^2z^2}\right|$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am stuck on this problem:

If $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{D}$, $f(0)=0$, $|f(z)|\leq 1$ and $f(r)=f(-r)$ for some $r \in (0,1)$, then $|f(z)| \leq |z|\left| \frac{z^2-r^2}{1-r^2z^2}\right|$.

So far I have the following:

Let $g(z) = \frac{z^2-r^2}{1-r^2z^2}$. Then it is clear that for $R<1$, $g$ is analytic in $B_R(0)$ and I can show that on $|z|=R$, we have $|g(z)| \leq \frac{R^2-r^2}{1-r^2R^2}$ so by the maximum modulus principle, $|g(z)| \leq \frac{R^2-r^2}{1-r^2R^2}$ in $B_R(0)$. Letting $R$ go to 1, we see that $|g(z)| \leq 1$ in $\mathbb{D}$.

Now consider $h = f/g$. By assumption, $h(0) =0$. I want to use the assumption $f(-r)=f(r)$ to somehow show that the singularities at $z=r$ and $z=-r$ are removable so then I can apply maximum principle to show $|h(z) | \leq 1$ and then apply Schwarz's lemma to $h$ to get the result I want, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unless you have $f(r) = 0$ the inequality doesn't hold (plug in $z = \pm r$).

Comment: ah, right. So then since they are zeros of f, they are removeable singularities of h. I missed something simple. Thank you!